# Is there any way to include spaces in keywords while running "npm init"?

Tags: npm, npm-init

I know I can always just go back and edit the package.json later, but I can't help but be curious: Is there any way to run `npm init` and enter a phrase with spaces in the "keywords" part of the form? For example, entering "platform api" results in the words '"platform' and 'api"' with the leading and trailing quote escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer:

*No*, unfortunately you cannot enter a phrase for a *keyword* via the [`npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) command that includes spaces, such as `platform api`, and expect it to become a single element within the resultant [`keywords`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#keywords) array of the *package.json* file.

The example below shows your desired valid result in *package.json*:

```json
{
  ...
  "keywords": [
    "platform api"
  ],
  ...
}
```

**Note:** Whilst the keyword example shown above is perfectly valid in `package.json`, it just cannot be achieved via input from the command-line using the `npm init` command. I would consider either:

- Like you say, retrospectively entering it into `package.json`.
- Or, just use a hyphen instead, i.e. enter/type `platform-api` via the command-line when using `npm init` command. - *Note: that would result in `platform-api` in package.json and not `platform api`*

---

### Long Answer:

#### Why is it not possible?

Your desired result cannot be achieved via the command-line using the `npm init` command because of the underlying source code in the [init-package-json](https://github.com/npm/init-package-json/) package that the [npm-cli](https://github.com/npm/cli) tool utilizes.

Let's look at the pertinent part of code starting at [line #210](https://github.com/npm/init-package-json/blob/2b5d21ea3e3434f8e0d6050cd2733d5062b830c6/default-input.js#L210) in the file named `default-input.js`. Here it is shown below:

***Excerpt from default-input.js***

> ```js
> if (!package.keywords) {
>   exports.keywords = yes ? '' : prompt('keywords', function (s) {
>     if (!s) return undefined
>     if (Array.isArray(s)) s = s.join(' ')
>     if (typeof s !== 'string') return s
>     return s.split(/[\s,]+/)             // <---- line #215
>   })
> }
> ```

On [line #215](https://github.com/npm/init-package-json/blob/2b5d21ea3e3434f8e0d6050cd2733d5062b830c6/default-input.js#L215), the part that reads;

```js
return s.split(/[\s,]+/)
```

the string, (i.e. the keyword(s) that you enter via the command-line), are split into an Array using the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. Notice the regular expression, i.e. [`[\s,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/3gqSLi/1), is used as the *separator* for the `split()` method. This essentially splits the string wherever there is a space character(s) and/or comma(s). It's particularly this part that makes your requirement not possible.

#### How could it be possible?

If [line #215](https://github.com/npm/init-package-json/blob/2b5d21ea3e3434f8e0d6050cd2733d5062b830c6/default-input.js#L215) was changed to:

```js
return s.split(/,\s/)
```

whereby a comma followed by a space was used as the *separator* for the `split()` method. Then let's say via the `npm init` command for *keywords* you entered:

```
platform api, foobar, quux
```

that would result in the following `keywords` entry in your resultant *package.json*:

```json
{
  ...
  "keywords": [
    "platform api",
    "foobar",
    "quux"
  ],
  ...
}
```

<sub>**Caution:** Whilst the **How could it be possible** section describes what changes are necessary to the source code to achieve your desired requirement, I am not implying, nor suggesting, that you change the source code.</sub>